# Time Machine completed a verification of your backups. To improve reliability, Time Machine must create a new backup for you

Tags: time-machine, backup, time-capsule

since upgrading to El Capitan, every time my machine tries to make a backup to my Time Capsule, it prompts me with the aforementioned message.

after researching and finding not much, I decided to blow away my long history of backups and create a new one as suggested.  the backup succeeded but the second time it tried to do a backup it failed again.

so now I have to create a brand new backup (of the whole disk) every time I want to make a backup?

this worked fine on Yosemite!

help?

Comment: I have a similar problem as well. Have you been experiencing network intermittency with your computer during TM backups? My question is here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/227875/162909

Comment: There's always the possibility that the Time Capsule's storage is failing. I don't own one so I don't know how to test it - but that would be my first port of call.

Comment: it's not a network intermittency issue.  I get the same error message if I plug my laptop into the Time Capsule directly (wired).  and it's not a problem with the TC either.  I have other MBPs that back up to it (not upgraded to El Capitan) that work just fine.  this is an El Capitan problem

Comment: I'm getting the same thing trying to back up to a Drobo 5N. Interesting to hear it's also happening with a Time Capsule.

Comment: I'm having this issue over a Synology NAS, and it's making me worried about my NAS itself; but all the verification tools available there seem to be happy as a clam … I wish someone could dig up some information about what actually *causes* this error (corrupted files, or metadata? Something to do with permissions or x-attrs?), so I could *manually* fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the problem was Apple's after all.  they never admitted there was a problem but the latest firmware upgrade for the Time Capsule fixed the problem.  it hasn't failed to back up even once since the upgrade

Comment: What firmware version are you using that you think fixes it?  You should be able to check from AirPort Utility.

Comment: I'm using version 7.7.8