# Time machine always needs to restart

Tags: time-machine

Time Machine says 100% of the time after a backup that verifcation failed and it needs to re-do the backup.

[image]

- I use a 4TB WD MyCloud and backup over wifi. The SAN itself is connected to the router via ethernet.
- I'm running OS X El Capitan (10.11.3).

How can I debug this issue?

Comment: Please provide more info about your system. What OS X version(s)? How is the target disk connected to the network? Have you already tried reformatting the target disk? Etc...

Comment: @tim.rohrer just added that info. I didn't reformat the disk though. Even though that's a lot of work, I'm willing to do that if there's reasonable evidence that that will do anything. I'm a bit skeptical. The disk itself is probably ext4, and I haven't heard of anyone solving problems by reformatting. But could be wrong.

Comment: http://pondini.org/TM/FAQ.html is a very good resource for Time Machine. I would suggest formatting it as a Mac OS X Extended volume and try again. So both computers are running OS X El Capitan?

Comment: I had a similar question (found [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/227875/network-intermittency-with-time-machine-causes-a-completed-verification-dialog)) which was likely due to network intermittency. Is your network stable during backups?